# Using Checkout in Stripe with an existing database in NodeJS (Express)

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I have problems visualizing a way to integrate Stripe Checkout in my existing database using Mongoose in Express.
I create authentication with Passport and a User database with mail, name, etc.
But how to integrate Stripe in a way that if the user pays, he can access the website, and he can remove his subscription after in his dashboard for example ?

For the moment I have a register (then logging) page that creates a user and a Stripe Checkout for paying but I don't know how to link one to another.

I know my question is vague but I'm having hard time trying to visualize the way to do it.

A sample of my Express route:

```
    router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    let errors = [];
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render('users/register', {
            errors: errors,
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
        });
    } else {
        User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
            .then(user => {
                if (user) {
                    req.flash('error_msg', 'Cette adresse email est déjà enregistrée. Si c\'est la vôtre, connectez-vous.');
                    res.redirect('/register');
                } else {
                    const newUser = new User({
                        firstName: req.body.firstName,
                        lastName: req.body.lastName,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        password: req.body.password
                    });

                    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            newUser.password = hash;
                            newUser.save()
                                .then(user => {
                                    async.waterfall([
                                        function (done) {
                                            crypto.randomBytes(20, function (err, buf) {
                                                var token = buf.toString('hex');
                                                done(err, token);
                                            });
                                        },
                                        function (token, done) {
                                            user.resetPasswordToken = token;

                                            user.save(function (err) {
                                                done(err, token, user);
                                            });
                                        },
                                        ... Code to send mail ...
                                                res.redirect('/charge');
                                                done(err, 'done');
                                            });
                                        }
                                    ], function (err) {
                                        if (err) return next(err);
                                    });
                                })
                                .catch(err => {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    return;
                                });
                        });
                    });

                }
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a straight forward approach,here is the integration guide on how you can integrate stripe checkout (for subscriptions) using nodejs - [Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server#create-subscriptions)

After creating a customer and a subscription, you need to store the subscription details(that you will get from the stripe api) in a separate(or can use same User collection) collection with the `userid`( which can be queried/populated later)

For updating or deleting subscriptions, you can provide user interface in the web panel and can perform the action on backend using stripe SDK(through rest APIs).

For more details on performing actions on subscriptions and payment source, you can refer the [Stripe API Referenc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object)

**For using client only integration**

You need to configure products and plans in the stripe dashboard and need to enable client only integration.You can configure a webhook to notify your server with the changes in customer or subscription data to make changes in the database(Recommended)

For more details refer : [Stripe Checkout Client Only Integration](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client)

Comment: Well, I think it will be easier but thank you very much for your clear answer !

Comment: Well, using nosql its always easier to mould the database structure.Ease would depend upon your current structure.Good luck!

Comment: Is it possible to use the client integration only or have I to configure the Checkout Server ?